# How to build map file for kernel modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, symbols, map-files

I need to load 2 instances of a driver for 2 physical devices of the same kind on my platform. I have renamed all the conflicting function exports and I am able to load both the drivers corresponding to each of those 2 physical devices.

But, I am worried that there might be some sort of a conflict with regard to data structure between them at some point of time. In order for me to make sure that this doesn't happen, I need to see all the data being shared between them. I thought the best way is to generate a MAP file for each of the kernel modules.

Can somebody please tell me how to generate MAP files for kernel modules?

Thanks,
Pradeep.

Comment: Why would you want two different drivers for "2 physical devices of the same kind"? The driver should simply maintain different data structures for control/management of each device. If you really do have two separate drivers, how would they be sharing any data? (Unless you'd done something to make them do so.)

Comment: Good question. Right now, the drivers use the bus but in future, I am going to port one of them to PCIe while the other driver will continue to use USB -- thus maintaining 2 drivers. Well, the 2 devices are actually 2 independent WiFi devices for which I don't foresee any scenario where they need to share data.